# Unable to understand DataFrame method "loc" logic , If we use incorrect names of labels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using the method **loc** for extracting the columns with the use of **labels**. I encountered an issue while using **incorrect names of labels resulting in some output** as follows. PLease help me to understand the **logic** behind the loc method in terms of labels use.

---

```
import pandas as pd

Dic={'empno':(101,102,103,104),'name':('a','b','c','d'),'salary':(3000,5000,8000,9000)}

df=pd.DataFrame(Dic)





print(df)
print()
print(df.loc[0:2,'empsfgsdzfsdfsdaf':'salary'])
print(df.loc[0:2,'empno':'salarysadfsa'])
print(df.loc[0:2,'name':'asdfsdafsdaf'])
print(df.loc[0:2,'sadfsadfsadf':'sasdfsdflasdfsdfsdry'])
print(df.loc[0:2,'':'nasdfsd'])
```

---

OUTPUT:

```
   empno name  salary
0    101    a    3000
1    102    b    5000
2    103    c    8000
3    104    d    9000


  name  salary
0    a    3000
1    b    5000
2    c    8000

   empno name  salary
0    101    a    3000
1    102    b    5000
2    103    c    8000

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2]

   salary
0    3000
1    5000
2    8000

   empno name
0    101    a
1    102    b
2    103    c
```

Answer (score 1):

`.loc[A : B, C : D]` will select:

- index (row) labels from (and including) A to (and including) B; and
- column labels from (and including) C to (and including) D.

Let's look at the column label slice `'a' : 'salary'`.  Since `a` is before the first column label, we get empno, name, salary.

```
print(df.loc[0:2, 'a':'salary'])
   empno name  salary
0    101    a    3000
1    102    b    5000
2    103    c    8000
```

It works the same way at the upper end of the slice:

```
print(df.loc[0:2, 'name':'z'])

  name  salary
0    a    3000
1    b    5000
2    c    8000
```

Here is a list comprehension that shows how the second slice works:

```
# code
[col for col in df.columns if 'name' <= col <= 'z']

# result
['name', 'salary']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good description for all most used subsetting methods here:

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/06/select-rows-columns-pandas.html